# Using plt.subplot on sns.boxplot and sns.scatterplot in a for loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I've been trying to use `plt.subplot` on `sns.boxplot` and `sns.stripplot` in a for loop. However only one subplot is showing. Do you have any idea how i could fix this issue? Here's the code:

```
for Rab, pRab in zipped: 
    sns.set(font_scale = 2)
    with sns.axes_style(style='ticks'):
            fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize =(18,6))
            plt.tight_layout(pad=3.0)            
            sns.stripplot(
                ax = axes[0],
                data = unphospho_ratio,
                y = Rab,
                x = 'disease state',
                color = 'black',
                s = 8)
  
            sns.boxplot(
                ax = axes[0],
                data = unphospho_ratio,
                y = Rab,
                x = 'disease state')
            sns.despine(offset = 10, trim = True)
            plt.show()
            
            sns.stripplot(
                ax = axes[1],
                data = phospho_ratio,
                y = pRab,
                x = 'disease state',
                color = 'black',
                s = 8)

            sns.boxplot(
                ax = axes[1],
                data = phospho_ratio,
                y = pRab,
                x = 'disease state')
            sns.despine(offset = 10, trim = True)
            plt.show()
```

And here's an image of how it looks like:

[image]

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep plotting on the same axes, that is for the first boxplot and stripplot, you are using `axes[0]`.

Say data is like:

```
unphospho_ratio = pd.DataFrame({'disease state':np.random.choice(['PD','Ctrl'],20),
                               'y1a':np.random.uniform(0,1,20),
                               'y2a':np.random.uniform(1,2,20)})
phospho_ratio = pd.DataFrame({'disease state':np.random.choice(['PD','Ctrl'],20),
                               'y1b':np.random.uniform(0,1,20),
                              'y2b':np.random.uniform(1,2,20)})
zipped = zip(['y1a','y2a'],['y1b','y2b'])
```

Then this will work:

```
for Rab, pRab in zipped: 
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize =(18,6))
    plt.tight_layout(pad=3.0)            
    sns.stripplot(
        ax = axes[0],
        data = unphospho_ratio,
        y = Rab,
        x = 'disease state',
        color = 'black',
        s = 8)
    sns.boxplot(
        ax = axes[1],
        data = unphospho_ratio,
        y = Rab,
        x = 'disease state')
    sns.despine(offset = 10, trim = True)
    plt.show()
            
    sns.stripplot(
        ax = axes[0],
        data = phospho_ratio,
        y = pRab,
        x = 'disease state',
        color = 'black',
        s = 8)

    sns.boxplot(
        ax = axes[1],
        data = phospho_ratio,
        y = pRab,
        x = 'disease state')
    sns.despine(offset = 10, trim = True)
    plt.show()
```

[image]
[image]

If you wanna overlay the points and boxplot (which isn't clear from your question), you don't want to look at the plotting device `plt`, it should be `fig` after calling all your function:

```
for Rab, pRab in zipped: 
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize =(18,6))
    plt.tight_layout(pad=3.0)            
    sns.stripplot(
        ax = axes[0],
        data = unphospho_ratio,
        y = Rab,
        x = 'disease state',
        color = 'black',
        s = 8)
    sns.boxplot(
        ax = axes[0],
        data = unphospho_ratio,
        y = Rab,
        x = 'disease state')
    sns.despine(offset = 10, trim = True)
            
    sns.stripplot(
        ax = axes[1],
        data = phospho_ratio,
        y = pRab,
        x = 'disease state',
        color = 'black',
        s = 8)

    sns.boxplot(
        ax = axes[1],
        data = phospho_ratio,
        y = pRab,
        x = 'disease state')
    sns.despine(offset = 10, trim = True)
    
fig
```

[image]

Comment: Hi thanks for taking time to fix my issue. However, I want the boxplot and the stripplot to overlap, which is way I used the same `axes[0]` and `axes[1]`.

Comment: @AlexL it was clear in your question what is the end point. see edit

Comment: Oh I'm so sorry, for some reason I missed the last part of your post, thanks so much man! :)